# Paying for a transaction that will happen later

Tags: solidity, transactions

I have a voting contract that opens and closes every 5 minutes. I don't want the owner to have two transactions for open and close. Is there a way I can have the owner pay for the close transaction when the vote is opened?

Comment: By 'owner pays for the close transaction' do you mean paying the gas fees?

Comment: yes Lauri gives a better solution to my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is bind the opening and closing to a timestamp. Transactions have access to the current timestamp with `now` so you can simply compare that to the values you want. So something like: `require(1234 <= now && now <= 12345)`.

Keep in mind that miners have some freedom when setting the exact timestamp. So if the stakes are high enough a miner can modify the timestamp to his advantage. But if the contract doesn't hold very high Ether rewards then it won't be worth it for any miner.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question, but I'm also not sure what 'owner pays for the close transaction' means.

Comment: As I understood it, currently the owner sends a transaction "open the voting" and 5 minutes later another transaction "close the voting". My answer suggests another way to implement the logic